# Get documentation of Node Transformations Skeleton

Tags: cesiumjs

I couldn't find documentation that describes how to modify the skeleton of a model.

Following the example: [Sandcastle Model Node Transformations](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/?src=CZML%20Model%20-%20Node%20Transformations.html)

I saw that two properties are used: `Skeleton_arm_joint_L__3_` and `Skeleton_arm_joint_R__2_`, but I can't find any documentation that tells me which parts make up the model so that I can animate or fix them as I like.

I tried to change the properties described above but I don't get satisfactory results.

Can anyone help me in creating a walking person (with animation) who has both arms raised (Without rotation)? and to create one with both arms down?

Answer (score 0):

The names like `Skeleton_arm_joint...` come from inside the glTF (*.glb) model, where they are node names in the model's skeleton.  You can get a complete list for a given model by loading it into software such as [Blender](https://www.blender.org/) or [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/).  The model you've got here is called [Cesium Man](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Sample-Models/tree/master/2.0/CesiumMan), and Blender shows the following scene hierarchy in the model.  The "green bone" icons below indicate movable parts of the skeleton.

[image: Blender screenshot]

However I would caution, if you want to create a complex animation from scratch, there will be a learning curve.  It will likely be easier to use Blender's built-in animation tools to create something new and export it to a new glTF file, rather than try to programmatically move a skeleton around with JavaScript code.

That said though, if you just want to play Cesium Man's existing walk cycle, and modify some arm bones to be in a different position from the built-in walk cycle, you might be able to do that with your current strategy, now that you have the list of bone names.